# No Mouse or Keyboard on Any Game

Tags: mouse, games, steam

I have recently installed Ubuntu 21.04. The OS runs fine and I am able to use all apps. My issue is when I launch a game from Steam. I have no mouse. In counter strike I was able to click around with a seemingly invisible mouse and finally landed in a match. Once in the match the mouse and keyboard worked fine. In all other titles I did not have the same success. Mouse and keyboard work perfectly, launch a game and they disappear and become unresponsive. I can still use the keyboard to exit the game, and once out everything works as it should. I have tried running the games in with steam play enabled and disabled and there was no change between the two. I am using USB wireless mouse and keyboard.

Comment: there is a bug reported today https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956849 not sure if your problem is related.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't think I am experiencing that bug because my USB keyboard and mouse function as expected outside of any game menu. Also, lsusb shows my USB mouse/keyboard.

Comment: Please don't forget Ubuntu 21.04 was not a LTS release and is thus in it's final days of supported life; https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html